# Problems downloading extensions using Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

```
static void copyStream(final InputStream inputStream, final OutputStream outputStream, final Client client) throws IOException {

    if (client.getReqType() == ReqType.STREAMING_PARTIAL || client.getRange() != null) {
        copyPartialStream(inputStream, outputStream, client);
        return;
    }

    Site site = client.getSite(); 
    Qos qos = new Qos(site); 
    String siteId = site.getSiteId();

    byte[] buff = new byte[BUFF_SIZE]; // 1024*32
    int readBytes = 0; 

    try (BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream, BUFF_SIZE)) { 
        try (BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream, BUFF_SIZE)) {
            while ((readBytes = is.read(buff)) > -1) { 
                long startChunk = System.currentTimeMillis();
                
                out.write(buff, 0, readBytes);
                client.addSendSize(readBytes);
                KHttp.increaseTrafficLog(siteId, readBytes);
                
                long elapsedChunk = System.currentTimeMillis() - startChunk;
                client.addSendMils(elapsedChunk);
                
                if (qos.pause(client)) {
                    long sleepMillis = qos.getSleepMillis(client, readBytes, elapsedChunk);
                    if (sleepMillis > 0) {
                        qos.sleep(sleepMillis);
                        client.addSendMils(sleepMillis);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        client.setAbort(true);
    }
}
```

I am looking at code that provides a link to receive a file using Tomcat. However, if the extension is attached, an error occurs. Not all extensions, but only when the mp3 extension is attached, it is downloaded normally, and when other extensions are attached, an error occurs. It works even if there is no extension at all. I think there is a problem with this code. I hope you can tell me if there is any code with errors. :(

Comment: Please say where Client class is coming from, add the corresponding library tag if it exists.